# How to get extract rows after null records

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have an application and I have a reporting table in which there two columns for the actual date and expected date I want to make a query that will give me the result table from the given table.The actual delivery is not always on the expected date but is on the actual date and after some populating the data in the given table I need to write an sql that would give me the start date for the expected delivery and the actual date that for the expected delivery.

However, I am stuck on how to do this in SQL. I have tried several queries however I am stuck on how to get to the result, sorry I am a new bie to sql.

Given Table:

| Home identifier | expected_del | actual_del |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home1 | 2019-03-10 |  |
| Home1 | 2019-03-15 |  |
| Home1 | 2019-04-21 | 2019-04-23 |
| Home1 | 2019-04-26 |  |
| Home1 | 2019-05-15 |  |
| Home1 | 2019-05-17 | 2019-05-17 |
| Home2 | 2019-02-20 |  |
| Home2 | 2019-03-13 | 2019-03-13 |
| Home2 | 2019-05-10 |  |
| Home2 | 2019-05-15 |  |
| Home2 | 2019-05-16 | 2019-05-16 |
| Home2 | 2019-05-20 |  |
| Home2 | 2019-05-21 |  |
| Home2 | 2019-05-23 | 2019-05-23 |

Resultant Table:

| Home identifier | expected_del | actual_del |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home1 | 2019-03-10 | 2019-04-23 |
| Home1 | 2019-04-26 | 2019-05-17 |
| Home2 | 2019-02-20 | 2019-03-13 |
| Home2 | 2019-05-10 | 2019-05-16 |
| Home2 | 2019-05-20 | 2019-05-23 |

Comment: Yes understand your point, I have tried several queries using group by, order by and other but I didn't get a result that why I didn't mention it

Comment: Sounds like random writing queries. Because this is a filtering of results it is a `SELECT` query that just needs a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The actual delivery is not always on the expected date but is on the actual date and after some populating the data in the given table I need to write an sql that would give me the start date for the expected delivery and the actual date that for the expected delivery. I tried select home_identifier, expected_del, actual_del from atm_cash_pickup where actual_pickup is not null; however this gives me the below values,        Home1   2019-04-21 2019-04-23
Home1   2019-05-17 2019-05-17
Home2   2019-03-13 2019-03-13
Home2   2019-05-16 2019-05-16
Home2   2019-05-23 2019-05-23

Comment: Ah, ok, look at window functions.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

With window functions in `MySQL 8`, you can find your desired output like this:

```sql
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
        home_id,
        LAG(actual_del) OVER w AS prev_actual_del,
        actual_del
    FROM given_table t
    WHERE actual_del IS NOT NULL
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY home_id ORDER BY home_id, actual_del)
)
SELECT
    t.home_id,
    MIN(t.expected_del) AS expected_del,
    t1.actual_del
FROM given_table t
JOIN t1 ON t1.home_id = t.home_id 
       AND (t1.prev_actual_del IS NULL OR t.expected_del > t1.prev_actual_del)
       AND t.expected_del <= t1.actual_del
GROUP BY t.home_id, t1.actual_del
```

Upd: The same without `WITH` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    t.home_id,
    MIN(t.expected_del) AS expected_del,
    t1.actual_del
FROM given_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        home_id,
        LAG(actual_del) OVER w AS prev_actual_del,
        actual_del
    FROM given_table t
    WHERE actual_del IS NOT NULL
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY home_id ORDER BY home_id, actual_del)
) t1 ON t1.home_id = t.home_id 
       AND (t1.prev_actual_del IS NULL OR t.expected_del > t1.prev_actual_del)
       AND t.expected_del <= t1.actual_del
GROUP BY t.home_id, t1.actual_del
```

Comment: Yes this is working thank you, how could I write this without the with cause though

Comment: @AllenMiller, I updated the answer with the option without the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You want the earliest `expected_del` since the last `actual_del` row.

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Just do a reverse count of the `actual_del` to assign a group.  Then the minimum `expected_del` in each group is what you want:

```
select home, min(expected_del), max(actual_del)
from (select t.*,
             count(actual_del) over (partition by home order by expected_del desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by home, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f2edbd091d1cf921e79acd39ec7076c) is a db<>fiddle.